# mysql update multiples why doesn't it work? Oh and php also

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why this won't work, each line one by one works but not when I join them together...

```
mysql_query("
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='98' WHERE element='img1' AND property='left';
  SET value='67' WHERE element='img1' AND property='top';
  SET value='15' WHERE element='img1' AND property='width';
  SET value='15' WHERE element='img1' AND property='height';
  SET value='22' WHERE element='img2' AND property='left';
  SET value='49' WHERE element='img2' AND property='top';
  SET value='62' WHERE element='img2' AND property='width';
  SET value='75' WHERE element='img2' AND property='height';
");
```

I got the idea from the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773422/multiple-set-and-where-clauses-in-update-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Combine both answers you got and you got all you need to know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it by using CASE statment in one statment.

```
   UPDATE imageProperties
   SET value= CASE when element='img1' AND property='left'   then '98' 
                   when element='img1' AND property='top'    then '67'
                   when element='img1' AND property='width'  then '15'
                   when element='img1' AND property='height' then '15'
                   when element='img2' AND property='left'   then '22'
                   when element='img2' AND property='top'    then '49'
                   when element='img2' AND property='width'  then '62'
                   when element='img2' AND property='height' then '75'
               ELSE `value`
               END
```

Comment: That did work, but it removed all the data from the other cells in that column from 'img3', 'img4' etc

Comment: ahaa you have img3 and img4 ok i will update my answer

Comment: also can I do multiple cases?

Comment: you can do as much as you can cases

Answer (score 3):

syntax is wrong.you should have UPDATE imageProperties for each set:

```
UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='98' WHERE element='img1' AND property='left';
UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='67' WHERE element='img1' AND property='top';
UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='15' WHERE element='img1' AND property='width';
```

Comment: It's not liking the second line still

Comment: UPDATE imageProperties SET value='22' WHERE element='img3' AND property='left'; UPDATE imageProperties SET value='49' WHERE element='img3' AND property='top'; UPDATE imageProperties SET value='62' WHERE element='img3' AND property='width'; UPDATE imageProperties SET value='' WHERE element='img3' AND property='height'; 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE imageProperties SET value='49' WHERE element='img3' AND property='top'; UPDA' at line 2

Comment: is your DELIMETER ";" or something else?

Comment: No - this is not required. The update can be done with a single update statement (see `CASE...WHEN`). In any case, if you try and submit this as a single query it will fail as it's a multi-query and is not supported by `mysql_*()` (but is supported by `mysqli_*()`)

Comment: correct. either use multiple mysql_query() statements or use CASE WHEN solution

Answer (score 1):

You are terminating the statement with each semicolon.

This should work:

```
mysql_query("
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='98' WHERE element='img1' AND property='left';
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='67' WHERE element='img1' AND property='top';
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='15' WHERE element='img1' AND property='width';
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='15' WHERE element='img1' AND property='height';
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='22' WHERE element='img2' AND property='left';
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='49' WHERE element='img2' AND property='top';
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='62' WHERE element='img2' AND property='width';
 UPDATE imageProperties
  SET value='75' WHERE element='img2' AND property='height';
");
```